# Inject into the Startup class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

Is it possible to use an IOC framework like Castle Windsor to inject into the Startup method.  I mean something like this:

```
public class Startup()
{
   IMyObject MyObject = new MyObject();

   public Startup(MyObject myObject)
   {
      MyObject = myObject();
   }
}
```

I am trying to drop and create a database on startup using NHibernate.  Alternatively is there a "better" place to drop and create the database using NHibernate?

Comment: nhibernate doesn't support creating and dropping database.  you can clear a schema and recreate the schema, but not the database file.  Do you want to do that?

Comment: @Fran, thanks.  I will create the database manually.  I am talking about creating the tables.  Sorry for the confusion.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You are talking about the asp.net core Startup class, right?  Check your tags.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, no I am not.  May I ask why you assumed this? - I see that most questions like this reference ASP.NET Core.  Thanks.

Comment: Because of the `.UseStartup<Startup>()` in core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something like this for integration tests using specflow.

I have a NHibernateInitializer class that I inherit in all my projects that looks like this

```
public abstract class NHibernateInitializer : IDomainMapper
{
    protected Configuration Configure;
    private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private readonly ModelMapper _mapper = new ModelMapper();
    private Assembly _mappingAssembly;
    private readonly String _mappingAssemblyName;
    private readonly String _connectionString;

    protected NHibernateInitializer(String connectionString, String mappingAssemblyName)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("connectionString", "connectionString is empty.");

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mappingAssemblyName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("mappingAssemblyName", "mappingAssemblyName is empty.");

        _mappingAssemblyName = mappingAssemblyName;
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            return _sessionFactory ?? (_sessionFactory = Configure.BuildSessionFactory());
        }
    }

    private Assembly MappingAssembly
    {
        get
        {
            return _mappingAssembly ?? (_mappingAssembly = Assembly.Load(_mappingAssemblyName));
        }
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        Configure = new Configuration();
        Configure.EventListeners.PreInsertEventListeners = new IPreInsertEventListener[] { new EventListener() };
        Configure.EventListeners.PreUpdateEventListeners = new IPreUpdateEventListener[] { new EventListener() };
        Configure.SessionFactoryName(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionFactoryName"]);
        Configure.DataBaseIntegration(db =>
                                      {
                                          db.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>();
                                          db.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();
                                          db.KeywordsAutoImport = Hbm2DDLKeyWords.AutoQuote;
                                          db.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
                                          db.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
                                          db.BatchSize = 20;
                                          db.Timeout = 10;
                                          db.HqlToSqlSubstitutions = "true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'";
                                      });
        Configure.SessionFactory().GenerateStatistics();

        Map();
    }

    public virtual void InitializeAudit()
    {
        var enversConf = new Envers.Configuration.Fluent.FluentConfiguration();

        enversConf.Audit(GetDomainEntities());

        Configure.IntegrateWithEnvers(enversConf);
    }

    public void CreateSchema()
    {
        new SchemaExport(Configure).Create(false, true);
    }

    public void DropSchema()
    {
        new SchemaExport(Configure).Drop(false, true);
    }

    private void Map()
    {
        _mapper.AddMappings(MappingAssembly.GetExportedTypes());
        Configure.AddDeserializedMapping(_mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities(), "MyWholeDomain");
    }

    public HbmMapping HbmMapping
    {
        get { return _mapper.CompileMappingFor(MappingAssembly.GetExportedTypes()); }
    }

    public IList<HbmMapping> HbmMappings
    {
        get { return _mapper.CompileMappingForEach(MappingAssembly.GetExportedTypes()).ToList(); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the domain entities.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <remarks>by default anything that derives from EntityBase and isn't abstract or generic</remarks>
    protected virtual IEnumerable<System.Type> GetDomainEntities()
    {
        List<System.Type> domainEntities = (from t in MappingAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
                                            where typeof(EntityBase<Guid>).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                                            && (!t.IsGenericType || !t.IsAbstract)
                                            select t
                                           ).ToList();

        return domainEntities;
    }
}
```

Then in my global.asax Application_Begin event handler I configure it

```
    public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        private const String Sessionkey = "current.session";
        private static IWindsorContainer Container { get; set; }
        private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; set; }

        public static ISession CurrentSession
        {
            get { return (ISession) HttpContext.Current.Items[Sessionkey]; }
            private set { HttpContext.Current.Items[Sessionkey] = value; }
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Version version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
            Application["Version"] = String.Format("{0}.{1}", version.Major, version.Minor);
            Application["Name"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationName"];

            //create empty container
            //scan this assembly for any installers to register services/components with Windsor
            Container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());

            //API controllers use the dependency resolver and need to be initialized differently than the mvc controllers
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new WindsorDependencyResolver(Container.Kernel);

            //tell ASP.NET to get its controllers from Castle
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new WindsorControllerFactory(Container.Kernel));

            //initialize NHibernate
            ConnectionStringSettings connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Environment.MachineName];

            if (connectionString == null)
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(String.Format("Connection string {0} is empty.",
                    Environment.MachineName));

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString.ConnectionString))
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(String.Format("Connection string {0} is empty.",
                    Environment.MachineName));

            string mappingAssemblyName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NHibernate.Mapping.Assembly"];

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mappingAssemblyName))
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(
                    "NHibernate.Mapping.Assembly key not set in application config file.");

            var nh = new NHInit(connectionString.ConnectionString, mappingAssemblyName);
            nh.Initialize();
            nh.InitializeAudit();
            SessionFactory = nh.SessionFactory;

            AutoMapConfig.RegisterMaps();
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            ModelBinderConfig.RegisterModelBinders(ModelBinders.Binders);

            AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
        }

        protected void Application_OnEnd()
        {
            //dispose Castle container and all the stuff it contains
            Container.Dispose();
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest() { CurrentSession = SessionFactory.OpenSession(); }

        protected void Application_EndRequest()
        {
            if (CurrentSession != null)
                CurrentSession.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  What do you do when the application goes live? Obviously you don't want to drop the database and recreate it.

Comment: Also, where is SessionFactory declared? - it is used in Application_Start

Comment: Sorry. Yes.  There's a property on their global.asax class that holds it

Comment: To your first comment.  I wouldn't have the recreate schema stuff  in the app.  I use it to reset my integration test.   scripts.

Comment: Is SessionFactory a static variable? Could you add it to your answer? Do you create one instance for the entire app or one instance per unit of work? Thanks.

Comment: sorry.  i'll update the answer.  i was on my phone for earlier comments